# V-for with template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am using vue-bootstrap. I try to create dynamic a grid component that gets headers and datas. Since we will not know how many column passed to the component, we should check every item that are passed.

```
<template>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items"></b-table>
        <div v-for="title in items">
          <template slot="title.key" slot-scope="data">
            <input v-if="title.isActive" type="text" v-model="data.value">
            <textarea v-else type="text" v-model="data.value"></textarea>
          </template>
        </div>
   </b-table>
</template>

<script>
const items =[
      {'label': 'Description', 'key': 'description'},
      {'label': 'Name',  'key': 'name', 'isActive': true},
    ]
```

So, if isActive is true, then this template should be textarea(Column should be changed with textarea instead of input) However it is not working and no columns changed neither inputbox nor textarea and stay default template

Could you please help on these question.

Thank you

Comment: `items` should be inside your `data`. And you shouldn't use mustaches inside your attributes.

Comment: I used   <template slot="title.key" slot-scope="data"> and it did not worked as well

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: It should be `title.isActive`

Comment: Try `<template :slot="title.key"...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should separate `title` in v-for and slot-scope variable to avoid confusing:

```
<template v-for="title in items" :key="title.key">
  <template :slot="title.key" slot-scope="item">
    <input v-if="item.isActive" type="text" v-model="item.value">
    <textarea v-else type="text" v-model="item.value"></textarea>
  </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, the `isActive` property is present inside the object in `items` array, you need to access it as a property of an iteratee.

So the code becomes:

```
<div v-for="title in items">
  <template slot="{{title.key}}" slot-scope="{title}">
    <input v-if="title.isActive" type="text" v-model="title.value">
    <textarea v-else type="text" v-model="title.value"></textarea>

  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ittus's answer,after minor modification following way is worked.

```
<template v-for="column in columns" :slot="column.key" slot-scope="item">
<input v-if="item.isSelect" type="text" v-model="item.value">
<textarea v-else type="text" v-model="item.value"></textarea>
</template>
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/nardnob/wvk6fxgt/) for dynamic columns.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fields: [{
      key: "id",
      label: "Id",
      colType: "span"
    }, {
      key: "name",
      label: "Name",
      colType: "button"
    }, {
      key: "uhh",
      label: "uhh..",
      colType: "idk"
    }],
    items: [{
      id: 0,
      name: "Test 0"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "Test 1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Test 2"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template v-for="(field, index) in fields" :slot="field.key" slot-scope="data">
      <div v-if="field.colType === 'button'">
        <h5>{{data.item.name}}</h5>
        <b-button>Am Button</b-button>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="field.colType === 'span'">
        <h5>{{data.item.name}}</h5>
        <span>Am Span</span>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <h5>{{data.item.name}}</h5>
        Am Confused
      </div>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get these answers to work. Which actually helped me, was this:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-pass-cell-templates-to-a-component-with-b-table/106283

and this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/skirtle/6of9dnpz/

```
  toCellName (slot) {
      return `cell(${slot})`
    }
```

The key is that the toCellName returns the correct slot name.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use below snippet.

```
<input v-if="title.isActive" type="text" v-model="title.value">
<textarea v-else type="text" v-model="title.value"></textarea>
```